# in _default raise TypeError(f"Object of type {type(o).__name__} is not JSON serializable")

Tags: python, flask

### These are my codes but i am not sure why the error is still appearing, and I try to convert from Cursor to json but nothing is happening

#### in the following code i need is to take input from form and return data from mongodb server so i can take these data and apply some filtering on it

**filter.py**

```
# import json
from ast import dump
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, session, redirect
from app import db
import pymongo
from bson.json_util import dumps
import json
from bson import json_util


class Filter():
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def filter_tweets(self):
        conditions = {
            "filterby":request.form.getlist('checkbox'),

            "forlikes":request.form.get('likeElements'),
            "forreplies":request.form.get('replyElements'),
            "forretweets":request.form.get('retweetElements'),
            "likenumber":request.form.get('forlike'),
            "likenumber":request.form.get('forreply'),
            "likenumber":request.form.get('forretweets'),
        }

        session['conditions'] = conditions

        session['data'] = db.tweets.find().sort(str(session['conditions']['filterby']),pymongo.ASCENDING)

        json_docs = []
        for doc in session['data']:
            json_docs.append(doc)

        return json_docs
```

#### her as you can see my routes in ('/myTweets')  route to to apply the method to filter data after that it will return them filtered

**routes.py**

```
@app.route('/tweets/filter')
def filter():
    return render_template('filtering.html')

@app.route('/myTweets',methods=['POST'])
def filter_tweet():
    test = Filter().filter_tweets()
    return test


@app.route('/test')
def test():
    test = Filter().filter_tweets()
    return render_template('test.html')
```

#### and this is my js code to take me to the next route after submetting

**scripts.js**

```
$("form[name=filter-form").submit(function (e) {
    var $form = $(this);
    var $error = $form.find(".error");
    var data = $form.serialize();

    $.ajax({
        url: "/myTweets",
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (resp) {
            window.location.href = "/test";
        },
        error: function (resp) {
            $error.text(resp.responseJSON.error).removeClass("error--hidden");
        }
    })
    e.preventDefault();
})
```

**errors appering:**

```
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Aug/2022 14:22:18] "POST /myTweets HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hadim\Desktop\StageProject\Flask&MongoDB\env\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2548, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\hadim\Desktop\StageProject\Flask&MongoDB\env\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2528, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\hadim\Desktop\StageProject\Flask&MongoDB\env\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2525, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\hadim\Desktop\StageProject\Flask&MongoDB\env\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1823, in full_dispatch_request
    return self.finalize_request(rv)
  File "C:\Users\hadim\Desktop\StageProject\Flask&MongoDB\env\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1844, in finalize_request
    response = self.process_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\hadim\Desktop\StageProject\Flask&MongoDB\env\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2340, in process_response
    self.session_interface.save_session(self, ctx.session, response)
  File "C:\Users\hadim\Desktop\StageProject\Flask&MongoDB\env\lib\site-packages\flask\sessions.py", line 409, in save_session
    val = self.get_signing_serializer(app).dumps(dict(session))  # type: ignore
  File "C:\Users\hadim\Desktop\StageProject\Flask&MongoDB\env\lib\site-packages\itsdangerous\serializer.py", line 207, in dumps
    payload = want_bytes(self.dump_payload(obj))
  File "C:\Users\hadim\Desktop\StageProject\Flask&MongoDB\env\lib\site-packages\itsdangerous\url_safe.py", line 53, in dump_payload
    json = super().dump_payload(obj)
  File "C:\Users\hadim\Desktop\StageProject\Flask&MongoDB\env\lib\site-packages\itsdangerous\serializer.py", line 169, in dump_payload       
    return want_bytes(self.serializer.dumps(obj, **self.serializer_kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\hadim\Desktop\StageProject\Flask&MongoDB\env\lib\site-packages\flask\json\tag.py", line 308, in dumps
    return dumps(self.tag(value), separators=(",", ":"))
  File "C:\Users\hadim\Desktop\StageProject\Flask&MongoDB\env\lib\site-packages\flask\json\__init__.py", line 124, in dumps
    return app.json.dumps(obj, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\hadim\Desktop\StageProject\Flask&MongoDB\env\lib\site-packages\flask\json\provider.py", line 230, in dumps
    return json.dumps(obj, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\hadim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json\__init__.py", line 238, in dumps
    **kw).encode(obj)
  File "C:\Users\hadim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json\encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "C:\Users\hadim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json\encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "C:\Users\hadim\Desktop\StageProject\Flask&MongoDB\env\lib\site-packages\flask\json\provider.py", line 122, in _default
    raise TypeError(f"Object of type {type(o).__name__} is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: Object of type Cursor is not JSON serializable
```

#### pl

Answer (score 0):

`.find()` returns a cursor. If you want to output the data to json, convert it to a list first:

```
session['data'] = list(db.tweets.find().sort(str(session['conditions']['filterby']),pymongo.ASCENDING))
```